# Is it more efficient to query MongoDb for key=null or for exists=false?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDb collection with some keys that may not be populated relevant for all objects in the collection.  I will want to do queries that find all objects where these keys are NOT populated.

Would it be better to

- Always include the key in the object and just fill it with null?  `{'x' : 'banana', 'y' : null}` OR
- Don't include the key when it's not relevant `{'x' : 'banana'}`

I understand that I can query for the results I want either way (see [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying+and+nulls)), I'm just wondering which is considered "best practice" and why.

Note (in case it's relevant) that the collection has around 10 "required" fields and 3 of these "optional" fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on the semantics of what your app does with the documents in this collection. You will save yourself some space by not storing the `y: null`. If you do store the `y: null` you will have to remember that `y` technically exists thus you should query for `null`s in a certain way. If the layer above Mongo doesn't care then I would go for not storing empty field, just like @Derick recommended. If it does care, however, and you find it easier to work with the `null`s in your `y`s then go for it.

**UPDATE** To your question about the effectiveness. If you're doing everything right then you're working data set fits in RAM. With that said, I don't think there's a noticeable difference in either approach unless you index by `y`. In this case the behavior may be different but the best way to find out is to run some tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for not storing empty fields. However, it depends a little bit on what sort of queries you're going to run on this collection. If you can elaborate on that, I'll update the answer.